# Create a bootable image of a Linux installation

Tags: linux

I have a system that is running out of space.( I hardly have 500MB left ) I want to make a bootable image of my Linux installation and install it onto a laptop which I intend to use as my primary machine. I have tried both Remastersys and Relinux. But they both make directories under /home directory and hence run out of space real quick.

Is there a way in which I can change the working directories of either of the them?
Or are there any alternatives? I've heard of clonezilla but I am not sure how relevant it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no way to change their directories (I doubt), make them in some other place and put symlinks with needed names into your home. For example, if it creates ~/.foo, and you attached some external storage as /ext, make /ext/.foo and make symlink ~/.foo -> /ext/.foo. This will be enough for >99.9% of such tools.

Of course you shall have some external storage for this. If your laptop is modern enough, the simplest one is USB attached hard disk.

Many tools also allow to change their directories via environment variables, this should be described in their documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a great answer. Never thought symlinks could be this handy. I will make sure I set up LVM on my laptop. :)